# Java PKCS7 signature issue

Tags: java

I am getting ciphertexts with 'MIA' prefix when I sign using Java, but the correct format should start with 'MII'. I suspect this might be causing my signature verification to fail.

```
private String signData(String data) throws Exception{
        String result;
        String pfxFilePath = env.getProperty("path_to_keystore");
        String pfxPassword = env.getProperty("keystore_password");
        String alias = env.getProperty("key_alias");
        String algorithm = env.getProperty("signature_algorithm");

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");


        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pfxFilePath);
        keystore.load(is,pfxPassword.toCharArray() );

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        java.security.cert.Certificate[] certificateChain = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        final List<java.security.cert.Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<java.security.cert.Certificate>();
        for (int i = 0, length = certificateChain == null ? 0 : certificateChain.length; i < length; i++) {
            certificates.add(certificateChain[i]);
        }
        Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certificates);
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(algorithm).setProvider("BC").build((PrivateKey) (keystore.getKey(alias, pfxPassword.toCharArray())));
        CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(signer, (X509Certificate) cert));
        generator.addCertificates(certStore);
        CMSTypedData cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(cmsData, true);
        byte[] signedBytes = signedData.getEncoded();

        result = Base64.encodeBase64String(signedBytes);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Note that storing/handling sensitive info like passwords as PLAIN character arrays can expose them to potential memory inspection attacks! it is recommended to use a `ProtectionParameter` object to protect the private key entry in the keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the signature isn't DER encoded. Try this instead:

```
byte[] signedBytes = signedData.getEncoded("DER");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the signature has been successfully verified.

Answer (score -1):

Well, try using this code

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class YourClass {

    private String signData(String data) throws Exception {
        String result;
        String pfxFilePath = env.getProperty("path_to_keystore");
        String pfxPassword = env.getProperty("keystore_password");
        String alias = env.getProperty("key_alias");
        String algorithm = env.getProperty("signature_algorithm");

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pfxFilePath);
        keystore.load(is, pfxPassword.toCharArray());

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        java.security.cert.Certificate[] certificateChain = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        final List<java.security.cert.Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0, length = certificateChain == null ? 0 : certificateChain.length; i < length; i++) {
            certificates.add(certificateChain[i]);
        }
        Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certificates);
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(algorithm).setProvider("BC").build((PrivateKey) (keystore.getKey(alias, pfxPassword.toCharArray())));
        CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(signer, (X509Certificate) cert));
        generator.addCertificates(certStore);
        CMSTypedData cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(cmsData, true);
        byte[] signedBytes = signedData.getEncoded();

        result = Base64.encodeBase64String(signedBytes).replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).